# Changing the values on the path between two points in the matrix given the start and end coordinates

Tags: arrays, c, matrix, path

In the code below, there is a code that finds whether there will be a path consisting of 0 numbers between two points given the start coordinate and the end coordinate. But after I find the path, I want to replace the 0 values in this path with the value at the starting point. How can I achieve this situation?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define M 4
#define N 5
void dfs(int adj[][N], int i, int j, bool visited[][N])
{
    if (i < 0 || i >= M || j < 0 || j >= N || adj[i][j] != 0 || visited[i][j])
    {
        return;
    }
    visited[i][j] = true;
    dfs(adj, i - 1, j, visited); // Move left
    dfs(adj, i + 1, j, visited); // Move Right
    dfs(adj, i, j - 1, visited); // Move top
    dfs(adj, i, j + 1, visited); // Move bottom
}
bool hasPathDfs(int adj[][N], int sx, int sy, int dx, int dy)
{
    bool visited[N][N];
    int i,j;
    for ( i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for ( j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
            visited[i][j] = false;
        }
    }

    // Mark the start and end positions as part of the '0' trail
    adj[sx][sy] = 0;
    adj[dx][dy] = 0;

    dfs(adj, sx, sy, visited);

    return visited[dx][dy];
}



int main()
{
    // 2D matrix with 1's as blocked and 0's as path.
    int matrix[M][N] = {
        {0, 0, 1, 0, 1},
        {1, 2, 5, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 2, 0, 1},
        {0, 5, 0, 0, 0}};
  
    // Find path
    int sx = 1, sy = 2, dx = 3, dy = 1;
    printf("Find path from (%d,%d) to (%d,%d):\n", sx, sy, dx, dy);
    printf("DFS: %s\n", hasPathDfs(matrix, sx, sy, dx, dy) ? "true" : "false");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to read the value from the start position, and pass that into your recursive function that finds the path. Each time you set `visited` to true, store that value into the matrix.

```
void dfs(int adj[][N], int i, int j, bool visited[][N], int poison)
{
    if (i < 0 || i >= M || j < 0 || j >= N || adj[i][j] != 0 || visited[i][j])
    {
        return;
    }
    visited[i][j] = true;
    adj[i][j] = poison;

    dfs(adj, i - 1, j, visited, poison); // Move left
    dfs(adj, i + 1, j, visited, poison); // Move Right
    dfs(adj, i, j - 1, visited, poison); // Move top
    dfs(adj, i, j + 1, visited, poison); // Move bottom
}

bool hasPathDfs(int adj[][N], int sx, int sy, int dx, int dy)
{
    bool visited[N][N];
    int i,j;
    for ( i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for ( j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
            visited[i][j] = false;
        }
    }

    int poison = adj[sx][sy];

    // Mark the start and end positions as part of the '0' trail
    adj[sx][sy] = 0;
    adj[dx][dy] = 0;

    dfs(adj, sx, sy, visited, poison);

    return visited[dx][dy];
}
```